# React JSX Styling

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

So I'm working on a project, while I'm doing all my styling in a separate .css class. Now I have a function, and the props passed in is "active", either true or false. I want the div in the function to always have a styling (`sideBarOption`), then if active is true, it also has an additional styling (`sidebarOption--active`).  From a few tutorials this is what I got:

```
function SidebarOption({active, text, Icon}){
    return(
        <div className={`sidebarOption ${active && 'sidebarOption--active' }`}>
            <Icon />
            <h2>{text}</h2>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This code works, and it's able to apply the additional styling. I'm just confused how this line works, and what it does. Can you please break it down:

```
<div className={`sidebarOption ${active && 'sidebarOption--active' }`}>
```

Also if you know any other ways to add additional stylings please let me know. For example, is there a way just to use a regular if-else statement to apply additional styling?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **string interpolation**. This special quote >> ` << (AltGr + 7 (not numpad) on an azerty keyboard) allow you to add condition inside the string you are writing. It is interpreted and result in one string with the result of your condition.

Now, This condition of yours is kinda special, it's a trick from JS that allow you to write a ternary expression without setting an *else* statement. If *active* is false, then it won't try to resolve the second condition, it's called lazy evaluation, note the two '&'). So :

className={`sidebarOption ${active && 'sidebarOption--active' }`}

is equal to :

className={`sidebarOption ${active ? 'sidebarOption--active' : '' }`}

On the second one, I have written the ternary condition as you probably know it :

`Boolean ? 'true value' : 'else value'`

Now, if you want to write the condition in a more common way (if...else) then you'll have to externalize the string construction in a function :

```
const classes = () => {
  const classString = 'sidebarOption ';
  if(active) {
    classString += 'sidebarOption--active';
  }

  return classString;
}
```

And use it as follow :

```
<div className={ classes() }>
  <Icon />
    <h2>{text}</h2>
  </div>
```

In StackOverflow, this special quote is used to display code, so it's pretty hard to explain sorry, but information about it is easily found on google by searching 'string interpolation'.

Comment: You're awesome! Thanks for explaining it with the ? ternary expression, that makes more sense!